# Why is my canvas javascript not making connected lines?

Tags: javascript, canvas, bezier

I'm trying to create a canvas script that visually draws a cubic bezier-curve, but so far I've been unsuccessful making my lines connect. See the code here

```
 var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
 var c = canvas.getContext("2d");  
  // Bezier eq. code
 coord = function(x,y) { if(!x) var x=0; if(!y) var y=0; return {x: x, y: y}; }

B1 = function(t) { return (t*t*t); }
B2 = function(t) { return (3*t*t*(1-t)); } 
B3 = function(t) { return (3*t*(1-t)*(1-t)); }
B4 = function(t) { return ((1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)); }

function getBezier(t,C1,C2,C3,C4) {
    var pos = new coord();
    pos.x = C1.x * B1(t) + C2.x * B2(t) +C3.x * B3(t) + C4.x * B4(t);
    pos.y = C1.y * B1(t) + C2.y * B2(t) + C3.y * B3(t) + C4.y * B4(t);
    return pos; 
}
//Ctrl points.
P1 = coord(12,12);
P2 = coord(90,1);
P3 = coord(0,190);
P4 = coord(150,150);


t=0;
function drawbez() {
  if (t == 0) {var interval = setInterval('drawbez()',1);}
  var curpos = getBezier(t2,P1,P2,P3,P4); // Staðan í ferlinum
  if (t > 1) { clearInterval(interval); return; }
  c2.moveTo(curpos.x,curpos.y);
  c2.lineTo(curpos.x+t2,curpos.y+t2);
  c2.stroke();
  t = t+0.01
 }
```

Any ideas?

I did a code using random numbers using exactly the same drawing commands and that actually gave me connected lines.

See code on HTML [here](http://notendur.hi.is/~tkt1/canvas/bez.html)

Using Bezier-curves tutorial from 13th Parallel
http://13thparallel.com/archive/bezier-curves/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, I got it to work by changing your code to the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
// Bezier eq. code
coord = function(x, y) {
    if (!x) {
        x = 0;
    }
    if (!y) {
        y = 0;
    }
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
};

B1 = function(t) {
    return (t * t * t);
};
B2 = function(t) {
    return (3 * t * t * (1 - t));
};
B3 = function(t) {
    return (3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t));
};
B4 = function(t) {
    return ((1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t));
};

function getBezier(t, C1, C2, C3, C4) {
    var pos = new coord();
    pos.x = C1.x * B1(t) + C2.x * B2(t) + C3.x * B3(t) + C4.x * B4(t);
    pos.y = C1.y * B1(t) + C2.y * B2(t) + C3.y * B3(t) + C4.y * B4(t);
    return pos;
}
//Ctrl points.
P1 = coord(12, 12);
P2 = coord(90, 1);
P3 = coord(0, 190);
P4 = coord(150, 150);

t = 0;

var drawbez = function() {
    var interval;
    if (t === 0) {
        interval = setInterval(drawbez, 1);
    }
    var curpos = getBezier(t, P1, P2, P3, P4); // Staðan í ferlinum
    if (t > 1) {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        return;
    }
    //c.moveTo(curpos.x, curpos.y);
    c.lineTo(curpos.x + t, curpos.y + t);
    c.stroke();
    t = t + 0.01;
};

drawbez();
```

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/Y8QrR/) for a working example.

Basically, `t2` was never declared, `interval` was out of scope, the `setTimeout()` reference to `drawbez` seemed to be out of scope (possibly because you specified a string function name rather than a direct object reference), and removing the `.moveTo()` as mentioned in John Green's answer gave a much smoother line.

Comment: Quick note... interval is still out of scope.  It should be a global, since you'll check that every time you come back in.

Comment: @John - good point, yes it should be declared outside the `drawbez()` function. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some larger problems with your bezier (lineTo instead of bezierCurveTo or even quadraticCurveTo), but the disconnected lines is because you're moving the cursor between draws.  Comment out this line:

```
  c2.moveTo(curpos.x,curpos.y);
```

Or, probably more accurate:

```
  c2.lineTo(curpos.x, curpos.y);  // remove the moveTo.
```

And, partially because somebody accused me (rightly so) of pontificating earlier... I don't recommend Canvas for drawing curves.  The fundamental architecture is totally procedural, which can mean thousands of DOM drawing calls for even very simple images.  SVG is generally better to work with unless you need affine image matrixes for pseudo 3D or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic wasn't quite right. Your code constantly drew a line from curpos to curpos+t2 which was always going to a tiny line given t2 is always under one before you call clearinterval. I have adapted your code below, which store the prevcoord and draws a line from the previous coord to the new coord each time drawBez is called.

If you are going to do effective animation on the canvas, this is definitely not the best way to it. Try searching around for best practice on creating an animation flow (draw update recall etc).

```
 var canva2s=document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var c2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
    c2.lineWidth = 1;
    // Bezier jafna sett inn
    coord = function(x,y) {
        if(!x) var x=0;
        if(!y) var y=0;
        return {
            x: x,
            y: y
        };
    }

    B1 = function(t) {
        return (t*t*t);
    }
    B2 = function(t) {
        return (3*t*t*(1-t));
    } 
    B3 = function(t) {
        return (3*t*(1-t)*(1-t));
    }
    B4 = function(t) {
        return ((1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t));
    }

    function getBezier(t,C1,C2,C3,C4) {
        var pos = new coord();
        pos.x = C1.x * B1(t) + C2.x * B2(t) +C3.x * B3(t) + C4.x * B4(t);
        pos.y = C1.y * B1(t) + C2.y * B2(t) + C3.y * B3(t) + C4.y * B4(t);
        return pos;
    }
    //StÃ½ripunktar
    P1 = coord(12,12);
    P2 = coord(90,1);
    P3 = coord(0,190);
    P4 = coord(150,150);

    //var newpos = getBezier(0.2,P1,P2,P3,P4);
    t2=0;
    var prevCoord = null;
    //dir=0;
    function drawbez() {
        if (t2 == 0) {
            var interval = setInterval('drawbez()',1);
        }        
        var curpos = getBezier(t2,P1,P2,P3,P4); // StaÃ°an Ã­ ferlinum        
        if (t2 > 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }        
        if(prevCoord != null){
            c2.moveTo(prevCoord.x,prevCoord.y);
            c2.lineTo(curpos.x,curpos.y);
            c2.stroke();
        }        
        prevCoord = curpos;            
        t2 = t2+0.01;
    }
```